# How can I drag a borderless Kivy window

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Let's assume I made a kivy window without borders:

```
from kivy import Config

Config.set ('graphics', 'borderless', '1')
```

After that, it is no longer a pattern to be able to move the window with the drag of the mouse.
Now my doubt. How do I move the window by dragging the mouse?
There is a module in kivy, called MotionEvent, but I don't know how to use it for my purpose.

Is there a function, which I can always call when I click and drag the window, causing each pixel dragged to call the function, iterating Values ​​over the window position? Or a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably set `kivy.core.window.Window.pos`, that *might* be compatible with coding up a dragging behaviour but I don't know how well it will work.

Comment: But, how do I apply this? Is it a module? Could you explain?

Comment: `from kivy.core.window import Window` then set `Window.pos` to the value you want. You might be able to achieve dragging by detecting on_touch_move and setting Window.pos to an appropriate value. However, since that means both the touch and window are moving, I don't know if it will work.

Comment: That would be a hack even if it works. More generally you should use something like [this SDL2 API](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowHitTest) to set window regions that can be used to drag the window, but this requires Kivy to expose a window dragging api and I don't think it does right now.